# How to capture keypress in Jupyter Notebook on MacOS using curses stdscr.getch()?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, keyboard-events, curses

I'm using Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.7 on MacOS

I've collected a lot of data and now I want to graph it one at a time and cycle through the graphs using a for loop.  However I want to pause to view each graph - and press any key to continue to the next one.

I tried input('Press ENTER to continue...') but it creates a new line after each graph and makes the whole Jupyter cell output scroll up every time I press Enter because it makes a new line for each input.

So I'm trying to use the curses library stdscr.getch() to capture keyboard input - however it isn't detecting any keyboard key presses.

```
import curses

%matplotlib notebook
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
ch = 1

for col in df.columns:
    if int(col) % 2 == 0: # even columns are time
        xs = df[col] 
    else: # odd columns are voltage
        if ch == 2:
            ys = df[col]
            ax.plot(xs, ys, 'b')
            ax.set_xlabel('X') ; ax.set_ylabel('Y')
            ax.set_xlim(-30,260) ; ax.set_ylim(-10000,10000)
            fig.canvas.draw()
            #input('Press ENTER to continue...')

            stdscr = curses.initscr()
            stdscr.keypad(True)

            while True:
                key = stdscr.getch()
                if key != -1:
                    print(key)
                if key == 27: # This is the escape key code
                    curses.endwin()
                    break
            ax.cla()
            ch = 1
        else:
            ch = 2
```

However, in the while True loop, key is always -1.  No matter what key I press, key is always -1 which means that it isn't detecting any keyboard key presses at all.  What am I missing?  How do I use the stdscr.getch() to detect key press from within Jupyter Notebook on MacOS?

Thank you!

Comment: The example's incomplete.  Perhaps you used `nodelay`, etc.

Comment: You can use the `on_submit` event for the enter key. [More information here](https://minrk-ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Events.html).

Answer (score 1):

The Python code in any Jupyter notebook runs inside a server, and n/curses or any other library like that will try to get the keyboard of the server, or Jupyter will disable it. As such, ncurses will not be able to capture the key presses.

Your best bet is what @Tiago said: Jupyter Widgets and event handlers for that. But, this will only work for Jupyter, not Python running on bash.

https://minrk-ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Events.html

From the site above:

```py
t = widgets.Text(
    value='Hello World',
    placeholder='Type something',
    description='String:',
    disabled=False
)

def on_enter():
    print('enter key pressed')

t.on_submit(on_enter)
```

Answer (score -4):

As far as I know, you cannot capture keyboard input in Jupyter notebook. Jupyter notebook runs on servers which do not have keyboards.

Comment: I know of at least one way to capture keyboard input, which makes this answer false.